# Create data URI and include (defs) / use tags (linked svg's)

Tags: svg.js

I'm trying to create a data URL from my draw.svg() but the SVG.Use images aren't included.

First image is SVG with defs / use tags

The second image is the result of: `"data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(this.draw.svg())`

[image: my SVG I want to use]

[image: result]

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" width="1077" height="282" viewBox="0 0 1077 200">
<defs>
<image width="39" height="188" xlink:href="/img/Scheme AB - Boiler V3.70e12752.svg" id="SvgjsImage1004"></image>
<image width="130" height="107" xlink:href="/img/Scheme Q V3.c6849d30.svg" id="SvgjsImage1003"></image>
<image width="36" height="54" xlink:href="/img/Scheme AB - LLH V2.4840e136.svg" id="SvgjsImage1005"></image>
<image width="36" height="44" xlink:href="/img/Scheme AB - PHE V3.afba1279.svg"></image>
</defs>
<rect width="100" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
<use xlink:href="#SvgjsImage1003" x="0" y="81"></use>
<use xlink:href="#SvgjsImage1004" x="130" y="0"></use>
<use xlink:href="#SvgjsImage1005" x="167" y="127.5">
</use>
</svg>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the use is included. The images just don't load. I am not even sure if image references work in a data URL but try absolute paths with domain and everything

Comment: That's a great idea. I'll report back

Comment: It works! I included the Absolute URLs